# Javascript resulting in "SyntaxError: Unexpected token:

Tags: javascript

I'm Learning Javascript, and after putting this in, it results in a

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

error message.

Here is my code:

```
 var sleepCheck = function sleepCheck(numHours);
    if numHours >= 8
    {
        return("You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!");
    } else {
        return("Get some more shut eye!");
    };
    sleepCheck(10);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: `if numHours >= 8` should be `if (numHours >= 8)` Also, `var sleepCheck = function sleepCheck(numHours);` should just be `var sleepCheck = function(numHours);`

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about Javascript syntax.

Here is my correction:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
  if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  } else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
  }
};

sleepCheck(10);
```